# Can i do crud operation using `apache spark` with php and HBase database in Hadoop cluster

Tags: php, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, thrift

I have an `Hbase` table and I want to do CRUD operations in real time, and read-write using `PHP` with `Apache Spark`?

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: How does spark fit into this?

Comment: @BinaryNerd  I am new with spark but I want to do real time read write on hbase with apache spark . Is it possible with php or not ?

Comment: Forget Spark, and your question makes more sense, although it is so vague/asking for a tutorial that it is really off topic. Take a look at this: https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/php/DemoClient.php to get started perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you probably want to leverage the power of Spark while performing HBase queries from web application back-end. You may take a look at [Livy](http://livy.io/), but as I know it does not allows to create multiple sessions which is usually the case for a web application. And each session needs dedicating resources. Try first to use just HBase, since HBase can support very high rate of requests with low latency. 
If this is not the case please provide more details.